# How to properly load i18n resources in next-i18next from api endpoints?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

I have a nextjs app, which I want to extend using i18next and next-i18next (https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next).

The default configuration is looking for json files under `./public/locales/{lng}/{ns}.json`, where lng is the language and ns a namespace.

My requirement however is, that this should be served from an api endpoint. I am struggling to find the correct configuration, as `next-i18next` does ignore my settings right now and is not firing off any xhr requests to my backend.

next-i18next.config.js:

```
const HttpApi = require('i18next-http-backend')

module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'de',
        locales: ['en', 'de'],
    },
    backend: {
        referenceLng: 'de',
        loadPath: `https://localhost:5001/locales/de/common`,
        parse: (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            return data 
        }
    },
    debug: true,
    ns: ['common', 'footer', 'second-page'], // the namespaces needs to be listed here, to make sure they got preloaded
    serializeConfig: false, // because of the custom use i18next plugin
    use: [HttpApi],
}
```

I am at a loss here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Yes, I've solved it - just did not come around to answer my own question. I'll give it a go this evening

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eventually I cobbled it together.

```
const I18NextHttpBackend = require('i18next-http-backend')

module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'de',
        locales: ['de'],

        backend: {
            loadPath: `${process.env.INTERNAL_API_URI}/api/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}`
        },
    },
    debug: true,
    ns: ["common", "employees", "projects"],
    serializeConfig: false,
    use: [I18NextHttpBackend]
}
```

You might be running into an error saying   `You are passing a wrong module! Please check the object you are passing to i18next.use()`. If this is the case, you can force the http backend to load as commonjs, by using the following import:

```
const I18NextHttpBackend = require('i18next-http-backend/cjs')
```

The first one worked on webpack 5, while I had to use the cjs import on webpack 4. Although I could not find the reason for this.

After this, its smooth sailing:

_app.tsx:

```
/*i18n */
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import NextI18nextConfig from '../../next-i18next.config'

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalApp}>
        <PageLayout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </PageLayout>
      </MsalProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp, NextI18nextConfig)
```

anypage.tsx:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common', 'employees'])),
      // Will be passed to the page component as props
    },
  };
}
```

If you just need to locales to be fetched once, during build, you can use `getStaticProps` instead - that is up to you.

Comment: What should we do at API endpoint to return data translate back to Next.js ?

Comment: That is up to you. You have to have the localization data stored somewhere, retrieve it, put it into json or whatever and return it. Is there a concrete question? Disclaimer: I no longer work with NextJs at my day job and do not have access to the code anymore. I can't review it and give detailed explanations any longer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco! I am facing the same situation, but in my case I want to call API endpoint by Axios, so how can I implement Axios caller instead of XHR in i18next-http-backend ?

Comment: Hello Marco, please help me

Comment: There is no need to really, if you use the `i18next-http-backend` plugin, which takes care of all that. If you MUST use axios, you have to write your own plugin.

Comment: @Epple have you manage to worked out a solution? Im also trying to pull some translated content via API too. Appreciate if you would shed some light and direction!

Answer (score 0):

After long search for a solution i end up with this working example. Maybe it helps someone else.

`next-i18next.config.js`

```
const HttpBackend = require('i18next-http-backend/cjs');
const ChainedBackend = require('i18next-chained-backend').default;
const LocalStorageBackend = require('i18next-localstorage-backend').default;

const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';

const path = !isBrowser ? require('path') : false;

const localePath = path !== false ? `${path.resolve('./public/locales')}/` : 'locales';

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'nl'],
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  localePath,
  backend: {
    backendOptions: [
      {
        expirationTime: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
      },
    ],
    loadPath: `${localePath}{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`,
    backends: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? [LocalStorageBackend, HttpBackend] : [require('i18next-fs-backend/cjs')],
  },
  serializeConfig: false,
  use: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? [ChainedBackend] : [require('i18next-fs-backend/cjs')],
};
```

`pages/_app.tsx`

```
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import NextI18nextConfig from '../next-i18next.config'

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
     <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp, NextI18nextConfig)
```

`next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

const nextConfig = {
  ...
  i18n: {
    ...i18n,
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  ...
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And in API endpoint you need to call `loadNamespaces` function

`pages/api/some-page.ts`

```
import { i18n } from 'next-i18next';

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    ...
    if (!i18n?.hasLoadedNamespace('common')) {
        await i18n?.loadNamespaces('common');
    }
    const { t } = i18n!;

    const result = await sendEmail({
       subject: t('_EMAIL_FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUBJECT'),
       sendToEmail: email,
       content,
    });
    ...
 }
```

My locale files are located in this folder `public/locales/` so the full path of 'common' namespace is `public/locales/en/common.json`

Comment: it's not clean, you dont needs config `backends` option in your `next-i18next.config.js` file

Comment: @Epple is that all? Did my answer helped you to get the translations in your API endpoints?