# How to translate the REST API content through axios using i18next in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios, i18next, react-i18next

Almost I tried every solution found on Stackoverflow that didn't work for me in any way.

I am trying to translate the REST API content after fetching its data.

Here are below some snippets:

**i18n.js:**

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import axios from "axios";

const loadResources = async (locale) => {
  return await axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      params: { lang: locale },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data.slice(0, 3);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

const detectorOptions = {
  order: ["cookie", "localStorage", "navigator"],

  lookupCookie: "locales",
  lookupLocalStorage: "locales",

  caches: ["localStorage", "cookie"],
  excludeCacheFor: ["cimode"],
  checkWhiteList: true,
};

const backendOptions = {
  loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json", //used to pass language and namespace to custom XHR function
  request: (options, url, payload, callback) => {
    try {
      const [lng] = url.split("|");

      loadResources(lng).then((data) => {
        callback(null, {
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          status: 200, //status code is required by XHR plugin to determine success or failure
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      callback(null, {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  },
};

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    backend: {
      loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}",
    },
    detection: detectorOptions,
    whitelist: ["en", "zh", "jp", "fr"],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

**Demo.js**

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Demo() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.slice(0, 3));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}, [data]);


return (
    <>
    <section>
        {data.map((i, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div key={index}>
                <h4>{i.title}</h4>
                <p>{i.body}</p>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </section>
   </>
)
```

I don't know how can I load the translations from REST API content using Axios. But I know that `i18next-http-backend`  is used for loading the translations.

To be noted: I found these 3 links that don't help me.

- [how to load api response data as translation in React-i18next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155962/how-to-load-api-response-data-as-translation-in-react-i18next)
- [How can we load translations using api calls instead of having them defined in static jsons? How can this be done in React-i18next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748722/how-can-we-load-translations-using-api-calls-instead-of-having-them-defined-in-s)
- [How to properly load i18n resources in next-i18next from api endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67984807/how-to-properly-load-i18n-resources-in-next-i18next-from-api-endpoints?rq=4) (this is of next.js app)

`locales` are located in my public folder `public\locales\{lng}.json`

Also, This github issue I found where link is broken :(

[i18next-http-backend github issue](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/issues/117)

since yesterday I couldn't find any way to solve this issue. Also, it's confusing me a lot!

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('YOUR_API_ENDPOINT');
        // Assuming your API response has a field 'content' to be translated
        const translatedData = {
          ...response.data,
          content: t(response.data.content),
        };
        setData(translatedData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [t]);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data.content}</p>
      {/* Render other translated content */}
    </div>
  );
};

// LanguageSwitcher.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>English</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('fr')}>French</button>
      {/* Add more language buttons as needed */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LanguageSwitcher;
```

Comment: Im getting this error: `TypeError: key.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: do I have to cutomize something in i18n.js?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).